# Denote n'th order integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Is there a shorthand way, using the integral symbol $\int$, to denote the n'th order integral? I.e. much like how you can denote an n'th order derivative by the exponent $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$.

I've heard of using the integral operator $J_x^n$. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Well, if $D = d/dx$, and if $D^0 = {\rm Id}$ (as in $D^0 f = f$), then $D^{-n}$ is an option.

Comment: Often $f^{(n)}$ denotes $n$-th derivative, in the spirit of the Cauchy Formula then perhaps $f^{(-n)}$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration